# How can I resolve the "ERR_REQUIRE_ESM" error in my modules

Tags: node.js, typescript

Currently, I have a monorepo setup where my definitions are in a separate repo to be shared between my other packages. The structure looks like the following

```
.
├── frontend
├── backend/
│   └── indexes/
│       └── create-indexes.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── definitions/
    ├── index.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

My Tsconfig for definitions packages is like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonJs",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "baseUrl": "../",
    "types": [],
    "noEmit": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "files": ["index.ts"]
}
```

And my Tsconfig for my backend is like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "rootDir": "./",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Currently, When I run my script `create-indexes`. I get an `ESM_REQUIRE_ERR` saying that I am using require syntax in 2 files.
Utils and Telegram.

However, I am using `import` syntax as follows:

`import { 2 } from 'definitions';`

```
import * as xyz from 'definitions';
import { 1, 2 } from 'definitions';
```

I don't understand what the issue is since I am not using require. I would like to fix this issue by change the tsconfig in the definitions file and leave the one in the backend the same.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks